# Facebook og:description not showing in mobile. Shows in desktop browser

Tags: facebook

I have a page with a Facebook share button. In the head of the document I am using og:title, og:image, and og:description. When clicking the button from the desktop browser, everything shows fine. When viewing the mobile version (I'm using iPhone iOS 6), it does not show the og:description information. I've scoured the 'net but cannot find a solution. I have an image but I can't share it because I'm a newbie. Any ideas? Thanks!

Here are my tags with confidential info removed

```
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://staging-mysite.com/abc/assets/img/brian-320.png"/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="This is my title | Bill's Story"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="This is my description."/>
```

Comment: try different urls for sharing ur page & share the result please
for example if this your page example.com/mypage.php try this example.com/mypage.php?refresh=1

Comment: @PooyaEstakhri If I understand what you are saying, I cannot do what you are suggesting. These are corporate landing pages and have a fixed URL. If I'm misunderstanding you, please clarify. Thanks!

Comment: i mean there is no difference for visitors of google.com & google.com?heyjackareyouok=yes but it is different for facebook if facebook cached first url it will cache second one separately
so just add another variable  to your url (no need to process it in your code)

Comment: Understood. I added ?=test to the og:url META tag but that didn't change anything. As before, all information shows in the shared window from the desktop browser but the og:description information does not show in the mobile window.

Comment: dont add it to META tag add it directly to the url you share

Comment: It's passing the og:description to FB because if you go ahead and share the post, all information shows on your FB page - image, title, url, description, etc. The description just doesn't show in the preview window. I have to assume that it's because the window isn't large enough to display all information so it's being left out purposely.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out it's a Facebook real-estate issue. Since there is less available space in the mobile window, it doesn't show all information. When viewed in landscape mode, the information is there. Works from the desktop browser perfectly. It's a FB issue, not a programatic one. Thanks for your effort, @PooyaEstakhri!

Comment: Has there been any updates on if it is possible to do this? I am still not seeing description text on mobile safari on iPhone or iPad.